# The connection to snowflake via Excel VBA is not identifing the Table

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, adodb, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I am trying to do the connection with Snowflake via a VBC code. It is showing the message below.

> Details: "ODBC: ERROR [42S02] SQL compilation error:
>   Object 'BUDGET' does not exist or not authorized."

```
Sub VBA_SnowFlake_Connect()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sconnect As String

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN= Snowflake32;" &";HDR=Yes';Password= ***; Warehouse= TASKS"
conn.Open sconnect

 conn.Execute "select * from budget;"

conn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Here `…Snowflake32;" &";HDR=Yes';…` you have a double semicolon one in the end of the first string and one in the beginning of the concatenated string (this makes 2 of them `…Snowflake32;;HDR=Yes';…` also there is a strange apostrophe `'` behind `Yes` which I believe should not be there. • Note that you didn't ask a question (see [ask]).

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Roddy I have seen a question like this in the support queue if you cannot resolve it here.

Some tips I can share to help troubleshoot the "Sub VBA_SnowFlake_Connect()" is:

- Do you have a proxy set with the port number?
- Have you specified the database and Role, Schema, and Warehouse in the connection string that is authorized to access the table "Budget"? (IE are the grants on the object and role permitted?)
- Are the ODBC Driver, Excel VBA versions up to date?